# Move rows to different sheet after certain date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I currently have a script on Google Sheets that auto deletes rows after a certain date. However, I would like to change it so that it auto archives the rows to another sheet instead. I added in the target sheet , but I'm at a loss on how to move the rows, before it deletes.

```
function ArchiveOldEntries() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
var datarange = sheet.getDataRange();
var lastrow = datarange.getLastRow();
var values = datarange.getValues();

var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Archive");

var currentDate = new Date()//today
var yesterday = new Date();//yesterday
yesterday.setDate(currentDate.getDate() - 1);

for (i=lastrow;i>=2;i--) {
var tempDate = values[i-1][2];
if (tempDate <= yesterday)
{
  sheet.deleteRow(i)
}
}
}
```

Comment: `targetSheet.appendRow(values[i - 1])` above the `sheet.deleteRow(i)`

Answer (score 0):

#### Archive and Delete rows one day old or more

```
function ArchiveOldEntries() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");//source sheet
  const vs = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  const tsh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");//archive sheet
  const dt = new Date();
  const ytdv = new Date(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate() - 1).valueOf();//yesterday value
  let d = 0;
  vs.forEach((r,i) => {
    let cdv = new Date(r[2]).valueOf();//date is in column3
    if(cdv <= ytdv) {
      tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1,1,1,r.length).setValues([r])
      sh.deleteRow(i + 1 - d++)
    }
  });
}
```